# Force refresh from ViewModel where nothing changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using the MVVM pattern to create a list of data in WPF.  The data itself is displayed via a converter, which takes a DateTime and converts it to a flag:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    DateTime myDate = (DateTime)value;
    return (myDate > DateTime.Now) ? "after" : "before";
}
```

`myDate` is a property in a model object, which is stored in an `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel:

```
ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyModelList
```

This is bound to the view:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyModel.MyDate, Converter={StaticResource MyDateConverter}}" />
```

When the form initially loads, it correctly displays the text; for example, if the form loads at 12:00 and it's currently 11:58, it displays "before".

I'm using a timer to refresh this every minute:

```
void Refresh()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Refresh MyDate");
    RaisePropertyChanged("MyModelList");
```

But this doesn't work, because it only refreshes the list, not the bound date.  The only way I can think of to force an update is to iterate through the collection manually and update each date to itself.

Is there a simpler approach to this?

Comment: Did you try to use TrulyObservableCollection instead?

Comment: Do you have OnPropertyChanged in your setter?  It may not know when to update the view.  The binding looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one would raise the change notification on the item model.  If your items do not have that capability, or if you do not want to clutter the items with more data/capabilities, consider wrapping each item in an "item view model".

Alternatively, if your collection is small, and the timer interval is long enough, you could reset the entire collection.  It would be slightly cheaper to refresh the collection's default `ICollectionView`, which is what your `ItemsControl` ultimately binds against, though doing so is arguably a code smell:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyModelList).Refresh()
```